# How do I change a LÖVE2D game executable's icon?

Tags: windows, lua, love2d

I merged my `game.love` file and the `love.exe` with the command `copy /b love.exe+app.love game.exe`. But the resulting executable has the default LÖVE2D icon.

Is there a way to change that icon to another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about Love so I don't know if there is a built-in way, but you can change the icon of an executable file using a variety of icon editing software. Last time I did this in days of yore my weapon of choice was [IconForge](http://wordsmith.us/cursorarts.htm) but I'm sure there are other tools available now (like [these](http://icon-editing-software-review.toptenreviews.com/)).

Comment: Glad to help, but give it a little time before accepting an answer in case someone else comes along with a better approach. I don't use Love myself.

Comment: It looks like [that's the way it's done](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3642&p=37020&hilit=exe+icon+resource#p37020).

Answer (score 2):

The steps below are also covered in a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/WTk_HJdXVNQ) (icon topic starts at 2:22).

1. Create an .ico file using [GIMP](http://gimp.org/), you can use the `game.ico` or `love.ico` included in the 32bit redistributable of LÖVE as a template.
2. Rename your `.exe` file to `nonsense.exe` (explanation below).
3. Drag the `.exe` file into [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), unfold `Icon Group` and right-click the only item in it. Select "Replace icon ..." and select the `.ico` file you created.

   [image: resource hacker screenshot]
4. Press Save (floppy disk icon).
5. You might not see the change yet. Rename `nonsense.exe` to `yourgamename.exe` and it should become visible.